# Exception: In process hosting is not supported for AspNetCoreModule. Change the AspNetCoreModule to atleast AspNetCoreModuleV2

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to publish asp.net core 2.1 application to azure app service through visual studio and getting following exception. How to resolve this?

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.108\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets(49,5): 
Error MSB4018: The "TransformWebConfig" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Exception: In process hosting is not supported for AspNetCoreModule. Change the AspNetCoreModule to atleast AspNetCoreModuleV2.
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.WebConfigTransform.TransformAspNetCore(XElement aspNetCoreElement, String appName, Boolean configureForAzure, Boolean useAppHost, String extension, String aspNetCoreModuleName, String aspNetCoreHostingModel)
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.WebConfigTransform.Transform(XDocument webConfig, String appName, Boolean configureForAzure, Boolean useAppHost, String extension, String aspNetCoreModuleName, String aspNetCoreHostingModel, String environmentName)
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.TransformWebConfig.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
```

**Solution:**

Removing `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` from `.csproj` resolved my issue.

Comment: the solution has been added with question. I think it's more clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

Add this line to your web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

Or add this [property](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3606) in `.csproj` file.

```
<AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModuleV2</AspNetCoreModuleName>
```

**Update**:

Removing `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` from `.csproj` resolve my issue.

Comment: Adding `AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModuleV2</AspNetCoreModuleName>` to .csproj creates dependency error. But removing `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` from .csproj resolve my issue.

Comment: The webconfig part helped me. I copied some source code, including a reference to "AspNetCoreModule" (v1) from a different snippet.

Comment: Specifying <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModuleV2</AspNetCoreModuleName> solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

To get rid of this error, I disabled the web config transform by setting the [IsTransformWebConfigDisabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/#webconfig-file) property to `true` in my csproj file. A web.config file is useless when using Kestrel on macOS anyway, not sure why the build system tries to transform a non-existent web.config file on macOS in the first place.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```